# adding vanilla extract to cooled pudding

Tags: vanilla, pudding, extracts

I made a pudding from scratch and put it to cool in fridge. Three hours later realized I had forgotten the vanilla! Can I add vanilla to the pudding and whisk it really well? Or just forget about it?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that should be fine. If you have trouble mixing it in thoroughly, try reheating the pudding in the microwave, a few seconds at a time, to make it thinner and more stirrable. (It’ll re-thicken when cooled.)